# Is there such a thing as TapeMACS data file formatting?

Tags: csv

I'm trying to do an estimate for a data integration, and the client sent across some files for their current system that appear to be in TapeMACS format? It is not a comma-separated or tab-delimited format, and there appears to be a layout that maps to the file with "Field Name", "Description", "Format" and "Position" specified. Is this an outdated system, and can you provide any further information? Will I need to write a custom parser? Thanks.

Comment: Hi hal100001, do you have a sample of that TapeMAC file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an ASCII file format related to Ecometry, an e-commerce software.